# Vertical spacing of cells containing a parbox

Tags: height, cell, tabular

I have a complicated longtable with several levels of nested tabular environments. To get text wrapping inside cells and have the contents aligned at the top I use \parbox[t][][t], however, the height of the parbox is computed without any margin such that the following \hline overlaps with the text.

A minimal example to reproduce this behavior is

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular} {|p{0.2\textwidth}|}
  \hline

  This cell looks good. \\
  \hline

  \parbox[t][][t]{1.0\linewidth}{
    Not so happy with this.
  } \\
  \hline

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

This produces the following output (sorry, can't post images yet):
[image of generated output](http://img.im/i/ixoe47)

Of course, there is no reason to use a parbox in example above, but I need them in the actual document.

I would like to avoid providing the height of the parbox (such as \parbox[t][5cm][t]). Is there a clean way to add a margin either to the bottom of a parbox or before an hline?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to answer my own question, but I have found a solution by adding vspace to each cell *outside* the parbox.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\pb}[1]{\parbox[t][][t]{1.0\linewidth}{#1} \vspace{-2pt}}

\begin{tabular} {|p{0.2\textwidth}|}
  \hline

  This cell looks good. \\
  \hline

  \pb{
    Now I'm happy with this.
  } \\
  \hline

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The output: [image of generated output](http://img.im/i/l1uqn8)

I missed that before because I didn't have a space between the closing brace of the parbox and the vspace. Turns out that space is crucial.