# How to create a 3 column table with merge header in Latex

Tags: latex

[image: Model Table]

This is an example of the table I wish to do in Latex. This table is part of a set that should look like this:

[image: Complete set of tables]

I have tried to use the usual table and other variations, but usually the tables end up overlapping and occupying the whole page.

What will an example code to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what your problem is:

- If you need to merge several cells, you have to use the `\multicolumn`-command.
- If you want to place two tables side-by-side, you could combine several minipages
- If you want to content of cell to include linebreaks, try embedding the content in a `parbox` / `minipage`.

Here is an example that demonstrates solutions for all of the above mentioned problems:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,includeheadfoot,margin=1.54cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
    \begingroup
    \parfillskip=0pt

    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth}

            \begin{tabular}{| c | c | c |}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Archae}\\
            \hline
            \begin{minipage}{2cm}{\centering structures with non-immunoglobin}\end{minipage} & 
            \begin{minipage}{2cm}{\centering structures with Immunoglobin}\end{minipage}  & 
            \begin{minipage}{2cm}{\centering total of proteins found}\end{minipage} \\
            \hline
            1 & 16 & 17 \\
            \hline
            \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}%
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
            \begin{tabular}{| c | c | c |}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Bacteria}\\
            \hline
            \begin{minipage}{2cm}{\centering structures with non-immunoglobin}\end{minipage} & 
            \begin{minipage}{2cm}{\centering structures with Immunoglobin}\end{minipage}  & 
            \begin{minipage}{2cm}{\centering total of proteins found}\end{minipage} \\
            \hline
            11 & 16 & 27 \\
            \hline
            \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}%
    \par\endgroup
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The output looks like this
[image]

**Update**
You might have to adjust the vertical spacing for cells containing a `parbox`. To see how to do this, read this [Stackoverflow-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18100186/vertical-spacing-of-cells-containing-a-parbox) or this [stackexchange-question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147356/top-padding-inside-tabular-when-using-parbox)

Comment: Thank you so much! That is exactly what I was looking for. I apologize if I wasn't too direct about it.